# Sql query return only matched column from where clause having multiple condtions

Tags: sql, postgresql

User table:

| id | first_name | last_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | C1 | ABC |
| 2 | C2 | XYZ |
| 3 | C3 | PQR |

Query:

```
select first_name,last_name  
from user 
where "first_name" like '%AB%' or where "last_name" like '%AB%'
```

Result

| id | first_name | last_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | C1 | ABC |

I need the query to return only matched column from user table, here last name is matching with AB so it should return `last_name` value, and `first_name` should be returned as null.

How to do this?

Expected result should be

| id | first_name | last_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | ABC |

Answer (score 3):

You could use `CASE` expressions here:

```sql
SELECT
    id,
    CASE WHEN first_name LIKE '%AB%' THEN first_name END AS first_name,
    CASE WHEN last_name  LIKE '%AB%' THEN last_name  END AS last_name
FROM user
WHERE
    first_name LIKE '%AB%' OR last_name LIKE '%AB%'
ORDER BY
    id;
```

The above query assumes that you want to include a record in the result set only if either the first or last name matches.  If you want to show all records, even if neither name column matches, then just remove the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Tim's answer is perfectly correct.  But if you want to include the comparison logic only once, you can use a lateral join:

```
SELECT u.id, v.*
FROM user u CROSS JOIN LATERAL
     (VALUES (CASE WHEN first_name LIKE '%AB%' THEN first_name END,
              CASE WHEN last_name  LIKE '%AB%' THEN last_name  END 
             )
     ) v(first_name, last_name)
WHERE v.first_name IS NOT NULL OR v.last_name IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY id;
```